# Using preg_match and stopping at image SRC

Tags: php, preg-match

So I am using the `preg_match()` function to extract the SRC file name of an image and that part is working well.

The problem though is it isn't stopping at the closing quotation marks of the src field. It keeps going to including "some" other stuff in the image tag but then just stops. I really just want the src URL only.

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $rss, $image);
echo $image['src'];
```

Comment: Dont use regular expression to parse HTML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, this may work

```
$regex = '/src="(.+?)"/';
then preg_match($regex,$rss,$image);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am doing this with;
preg_match('#src.*=.*".*"',$stringToMatch,$result);

Answer (score 0):

Besides I don't advise to parse HTML like this, but this would work for you;

```
$str = '<img src="to/file/img.png" width="100">';
preg_match('~<img.*?src=[\'"]*(?P<src>[^\s\'"]*)~i', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```